# Best practice to use AD security group as distribution group in o365

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

O365 question.

We have our on premise Active Directory setup to Sync with O365.  In active directory I have a security group named "Quickbooks Users" which gives those users access to the quickbooks files on our file server.  I would like to setup a distribution group that is dynamic to the security group so I do not have to maintain 2 different groups.  Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?  I don't even see AD security groups in Exchange to convert them to Mail Enabled security groups and I do not see a way to create a dynamic group based on another group.

Comment: Are you sure you enabled all the default features of AD connect? I’m not able to take a look at this very moment. But I’ve setup a bunch of Office 365 accounts and it seems like this all just worked. I have several instances of AD user groups being tied to O365 distribution lists. Did you look under the Office 365 admin center for those users and missing groups? You can also look directly in Azure AD through portal.azure.com. You can definitely do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a synced group, it needs to be mail-enabled locally first, then sync it to Office 365 and it should show up as a distribution list in Exchange Online.  You don't manage two objects - just the local one, as you add or remove members the cloud object will be updated when the sync runs.